# BackHandler Is Not Working Correctly

Tags: react-native, expo

Native , I am working with react-navigation system , i have a Application containing Screens, If i Am in the Main screen and press the Back button in Android I want to App to Quit, But If i press android Back Button from other screens my app quits , which i don't what that to happen ,

My first Screen is the Login , second is the signup and third is the Main screen ,

I have Used this code on my Main screen

```
componentDidMount() {
 BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.BackButtonPressed.bind(this));
}


BackButtonPressed() {
  if(this.props.navigation.state.routeName === "Dashboard") {
    BackHandler.exitApp();
    return true;
  } else {
  return false;
  }

}
componentWillUnMount() {    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.BackButtonPressed.bind(this));
}
```

this is the Pages

```
const DrawersNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
      'Screen1':{ screen: StackNavigator({
      'Dashboard': { screen: Dashboard},
      'CP': { screen: MainScreen },
      'Polls': { screen: Polls },
      'Classified': { screen: Classifieds},
      'Customers': { screen: Customers },
      'Maps': { screen: Maps},
      'AllBusinessPartners': { screen: AllBusinessPartners },
      'Blog': {screen: Blog},
      'PrivatePolicy' : {screen: PrivatePolicy}
      }, {
        headerMode: 'none',
        transitionConfig: () => ({
          transitionSpec: {
            duration: 0
          }
        })
        })
      }},
      {
        drawerWidth: 250,
        contentComponent: props => <SideScreen {...props}/>
      })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using expo than you have to run it in `Debug Js remotely` mode. Then only backhander will work otherwise it won't work

Comment: You right, with Debug Js remotely it's work for me..but when i export apk it's don't work..so how can handle this?